# Java Map: Reverse chronological order

Tags: java, dictionary, iteration, comparator

I have the following function which should return a map of dates to longs such that you iterate through the entries in reverse chronological order.

`counts` is a `LinkedHashMap`, so the entries are stored in the order they were inserted (which is chronological in this case):

```
public Map<Date, Long> getCountsChronological() {
   Map<Date, Long> chronologicalMap =
     new TreeMap<Date, Long>(Collections.reverseOrder());
   chronologicalMap.putAll(counts);
   return chronologicalMap;
}
```

This function does not work, though it seems in theory, that it should. When I iterate through the map that it returns, I am still getting the entries in chronological order.

Comment: Appears? A short but complete example would really, really help. Note that the order in which `counts` entries appear is irrelevant.

Comment: okay, i edited the question a bit.

Comment: See my answer for a short but complete program which shows it working. Can you come up with a similar one with it *failing*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unable to reproduce - works fine for me:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Date, Long> map = new HashMap<Date, Long>();

        map.put(new Date(100), 100L);
        map.put(new Date(400), 400L);
        map.put(new Date(300), 300L);
        map.put(new Date(200), 200L);

        map = reverseChronological(map);
        for (Map.Entry<Date, Long> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey().getTime());
        }
    }    

    public static Map<Date, Long> reverseChronological(Map<Date, Long> input) {
        Map<Date, Long> chronologicalMap =
            new TreeMap<Date, Long>(Collections.reverseOrder());
        chronologicalMap.putAll(input);
        return chronologicalMap;
    }
}
```

Are you sure you're not iterating over the *original* map instead of the returned one?

Comment: Yes, it works for me too! Turns out I was fooled by the headers in a table I was populating. The list of dates that served as headers hadn't been reversed, so I was under the impression that the list of counts hadn't been either. It worked all along..